# Turning What If into Select Case

Tags: .net, vb.net

Question is, I basically wrote a Rock Paper Scissors game in VB.NET using If statements and wondered how exactly I would try and work this into a Select Case instead.

Professor was pretty awful at teaching things and didn't let us know until today that it had to be Select Case(its due tomorrow ._.)

Public Class Form1

```
    Dim randomGenerator As New Random


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub


    Private Sub rdoROCK_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdoROCK.CheckedChanged
        If rdoROCK.Checked = True Then
            picROCK.Visible = True
        Else
            picROCK.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rdoPAPER_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdoPAPER.CheckedChanged
        If rdoPAPER.Checked = True Then
            picPAPER.Visible = True
        Else
            picPAPER.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub rdoSCISSORS_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdoSCISSORS.CheckedChanged
        If rdoSCISSORS.Checked = True Then
            picSCISSORS.Visible = True
        Else
            picSCISSORS.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnSTART_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSTART.Click
        Dim computerChoice As Integer

        randomGenerator.Next(1, 4)
        computerChoice = randomGenerator.Next(1, 4)

        'If computerChoice = 1 Then
        'picROCK2.Visible = True
        'ElseIf computerChoice = 2 Then
        'picPAPER2.Visible = True
        'ElseIf computerChoice = 3 Then
        'picSCISSORS2.Visible = True
        'End If

        If computerChoice = 1 Then
            picROCK2.Visible = True
            If rdoROCK.Checked = True Then
                lbltie.Visible = True
            ElseIf rdoPAPER.Checked = True Then
                lblwin.Visible = True
            ElseIf rdoSCISSORS.Checked = True Then
                lbllose.Visible = True
            End If
        End If

        If computerChoice = 2 Then
            picPAPER2.Visible = True
            If rdoROCK.Checked = True Then
                lbllose.Visible = True
            ElseIf rdoPAPER.Checked = True Then
                lbltie.Visible = True
            ElseIf rdoSCISSORS.Checked = True Then
                lblwin.Visible = True
            End If
        End If

        If computerChoice = 3 Then
            picSCISSORS2.Visible = True
            If rdoROCK.Checked = True Then
                lblwin.Visible = True
            ElseIf rdoPAPER.Checked = True Then
                lbllose.Visible = True
            ElseIf rdoSCISSORS.Checked = True Then
                lbltie.Visible = True
            End If
        End If




    End Sub

    Private Sub Label5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblwin.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        picROCK.Visible = False
        picROCK2.Visible = False
        picPAPER2.Visible = False
        picPAPER.Visible = False
        picSCISSORS.Visible = False
        picSCISSORS2.Visible = False
        lblwin.Visible = False
        lbltie.Visible = False
        lbllose.Visible = False
        rdoROCK.Checked = False
        rdoPAPER.Checked = False
        rdoSCISSORS.Checked = False

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: don't for get Case Else UseShotgun() ;)

Comment: A Real Programmer™ would use an arrays of controls so neither If nor Select statements are used.  Look-up DRY (don't repeat yourself).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for the 1, 2, or 3 to be your `Select Case` - it would look something like:

```
Select Case computerChoice
    Case 1
        ' Do what's currently in your [if computerChoice = 1] section
    Case 2
        ' Do what's currently in your [if computerChoice = 2] section
    Case 3
        ' Do what's currently in your [if computerChoice = 3] section
End Select
```

Comment: so the Case # would be consistent with the random generated number to decide what the computer chooses?

Comment: Without looking at your program's logic, a `Select Case` statement is the same thing as an `If` statement, just with a few different rules. If your `If computerChoice = ` statements are working properly, then the `Select Case` will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: so in the previous, I'd turn it into something of this nature? http://pastebin.com/A39nujdw

Comment: Except obv there would be End Select instead of End case, my bad ^^

Comment: No, it would be more like: http://pastebin.com/tyafq3dX - you can't `Select Case` on multiple checkboxes - those you have to do the old fashioned way.  A `Select Case` allows you to take a single value (such as `computerChoice`), and check it against multiple values. It's not designed to help you when you're checking multiple scenarios (like whether or not three different checkboxes are checked).

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your code using a `Select Case`:

```
Select Case rdoROCK.Checked
        Case True
            picROCK.Visible = True
        Case False
            picROCK.Visible = False
 End Select
```

Or for brevity:

```
picROCK.Visible = rdoROCK.Checked
```

Onto your main, I'd create an enum as well for readability:

```
Enum RPS
    Paper = 1
    Rock = 2
    Scissors = 3
End Enum

'now deciding what to show for win, lose or draw:
    Select Case computerChoice
        Case RPS.Paper
            UpdateFormOnPaper()
        Case RPS.Rock
            UpdateFormOnRock()
        Case RPS.Scissors
            UpdateFormOnScissors()
    End Select

 'a method to update the for Win, Lose or Draw for each choice.
 Sub UpdateFormOnRock()        
    picROCK2.Visible = True

    Select Case True
        Case rdoROCK.Checked
            lbltie.Visible = True
        Case rdoPAPER.Checked
            lblwin.Visible = True
        Case rdoSCISSORS.Checked
            lbllose.Visible = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the brief option; -1 for even suggesting `select case` to check a boolean.

Comment: @cHao: you'd downvote me for that? He explicitly asked for 'how can this be done with select case'? :)

Comment: @p.campbell: Damn right i'd vote you down for that.  Else next thing i know, i'll end up looking at it in real live code when someone else sees this and thinks it's a good idea.  :)

Comment: @chao: unbelievable; you downvoted my answer for answering the guy's question, as well as offering the abosolute best solution below? To be clear: I did *not* "suggesting select case to check a boolean". I only answered his direct question, as well as some helpful advice.

Comment: @p.campbell: Nah...i didnt downvote.  The +1 canceled out the -1.  Net score: +0.  :)